# Corollary of Hoeffding’s Inequality

Tags: probability-inequalities

### Question

I am not from a statistics background. I came across the following corollary of Hoeffding’s Inequality and couldn't find the derivation or proof for it. Could anyone please share some reference of proof or just prove it here?

### Hoeffding’s Inequality

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n$ be i.i.d. observations such that $\mathbb{E}(Y_i) = \mu$ and $a \leq Y_i \leq b$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$;
$$
\mathbb{P}( | \bar{Y_n} - \mu | \geq \epsilon) \leq 2 e^{-2 n \epsilon^2 / (b - a)^2}
$$

### Corollary of Hoeffding’s Inequality

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n$ are independent with $\mathbb{P}( a \leq Y_i \leq b ) = 1$ and common mean $\mu$, then, with probability at least $1 - \delta$,

$$
| \bar{Y_n} - \mu | \leq \sqrt{ \frac{c}{2n} \log{(\frac{2}{\delta})}}
$$

### References

- Theorem 6 and Corollary 7 in [this pdf](http://cau.ac.kr/%7Emhhgtx/courses/AdaptiveFilters/References/Hoeffding.pdf)

Comment: Cross-posted and answered on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216245/corollary-of-hoeffding-s-inequality/4216260#4216260

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with putting the corollary in a probability form (note that $c=(b-a)^2$:
$$P\left( |\bar{Y}_n - \mu| \leq \sqrt{\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})} \right) \geq 1-\delta$$

Now, from the theorem we know that

$$P\left( |\bar{Y}_n - \mu| \geq \sqrt{\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})} \right) \leq 2e^k$$
where

$$k=\frac{−2n}{(b−a)^2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})}\right)^2=\frac{−2n}{c}\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})=-log(\frac{2}{\delta})=log(0.5\delta)$$

so

$$P\left( |\bar{Y}_n - \mu| \geq \sqrt{\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})} \right) \leq 2e^{log(0.5\delta)}=2\cdot 0.5\delta=\delta.$$

Multiplying by -1:

$$-P\left( |\bar{Y}_n - \mu| \geq \sqrt{\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})} \right) \geq -\delta$$

Adding 1 to both sides:
$$1-P\left( |\bar{Y}_n - \mu| \geq \sqrt{\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})} \right) \geq 1-\delta$$

but assuming $x$ is continuous, $1-P(x \geq z)= P(x\leq z)$, so:

$$P\left( |\bar{Y}_n - \mu| \leq \sqrt{\frac{c}{2n}log(\frac{2}{\delta})} \right) \geq 1-\delta$$

$\blacksquare$.